# WSO2 UDDI Service 404

Tags: wso2, uddi

I have the following version of GREG: wso2greg-4.5.3

While configuring all the stuff, having casandra correctly running, I'll get a working installation.

I have made some changes to the default port and added an offset of 2, thus I am at 9445.

Now I tried to get UDDI up and running. I followed the steps as of [here](http://docs.wso2.org/display/Governance450/Support+for+UDDI) and [second here](http://docs.wso2.org/display/Governance450/The+usage+of+UDDI+APIs)

Now I can query for sample the UserAdmin wsdl as of:

https:// stsmac.behrens.de:9445/services/UserAdmin?wsdl

But what I do not capable of is getting the UDDIInquiryService service wsdl:

https:// stsmac.behrens.de:9445/services/UDDIInquiryService?wsdl

My JAVA_HOME and CARBON_HOME are as following:

JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Home
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to /Users/lothar/develop/Projects/ReferenzProjekte/WSO2SOAArchitecture/install_root/governance/wso2greg-4.5.3

Trying to list all admin service in the OSGI console, I'll not see UDDI at all:

osgi> listAdminServices
Admin services deployed on this server:
1. ProvisioningAdminService, ProvisioningAdminService, https:// stsmac.behrens.de:9445/services/ProvisioningAdminService/ 
2. Service, null, https:// stsmac.behrens.de:9445/services/Service/ 
...

Any ideas, where to search why the UDDI services are not available?

Thanks, Lothar

My host is:

Darwin stsmac 10.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun  7 16:33:36 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1504.15.3~1/RELEASE_I386 i386

Answer (score 0):

after more research and trials I may have found the issue. In the osgi console I played with some commands and one of it was the setprop and props to see what is defined.

I assume I do not have any errors in my command line to start the services with -Duddi=enable.
After I have set the property in osgi cnsole with setprop uddi=enable I was able to simply stop all with Ctrl-C and then repeated my command to startup all.

That given I also assume the following: Is there a case where this property has not been setup correctly until I manually do it with setprop?

Also issuing another setprop uddi= has removed the enabled string, but I still able to start UDDI from the point I first set the property somehow.

Can anyone agree on this?

Lothar